# Haar measure on Homogeneus groups

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces

I would like to have a reference where it is proved that the haar measure of a Homogeneus group is the push forward of the lebesgue measure on the lie algebra through the exponential map. I have some notes but not real reference to quote in a paper I am writing. I remark that in the book by Folland it is not treated such an argument.

Comment: What is a "homogeneous group"?

Comment: A group connected and simply connected which algebra has a family of dilation, which is a family of lie automorphisms $\{\delta_\lambda\}_{\lambda>0}$ for which $\delta_\lambda\circ \delta_\mu=\delta_{\lambda\mu}$. You can therefore lift to the group these lie algebraautomorphisms getting group automorphisms with the same composition property I wrote above. In particular they are nilpotent. A non-eulidean example is the Heisenberg group

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to include this definition, remark about nilpotency and a reference since this is a nonstandard notion. Also, explain what a dilatation is since this is also nonstandard. (I would never have guessed if I did not know the dilatation used for Heisenberg groups.)